# Cross browser issue in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with vertical scroll bar. It is not visible in IE but it is visible in chrome & firefox.

I tried `overflow: auto; and -ms-overflow-y:scroll and auto` options. But it didn't work.

Can you please help me in this.

Comment: What version of IE? Also, please set up a fiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/ ) that replicates the issue.

Comment: version is :  11.0.9

Comment: Please share your code. If you really have `-ms-overflow-y` as well as `overflow-y` in your css, with different values, that would account for the differences in rendering. The -ms- prefixed properties are not recommended though.

Answer (score 1):

Please share a JSFiddle link to the problem to help explain more. From the top of my head. I think you need to set the `overflow:scroll` and the scroll bar will be visible in all browsers whether the container is filled or not. For the 'auto' option to work, your container must have more data to fill or go over the set height of itself for the scrollbar to show up. Otherwise it will not show up.

Here is a sample you can check on all browsers: http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/kkzvGm

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Nasir, Thanks for the reply,  I added that too

Comment: Can you share your html code please? Also what version of IE are you testing on?

Comment: I tried pen Sample, in IE but when  I tried the same styles not working for me

Comment: Please share your code here or using codepen or JSFiddle. Then i might be able to help more. Also please tell me the IE version you are checking in?

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: I'm not glad to hear it. -ms-overflow should not be used.